# Query with number after GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query to get data like this : .....

```
WHERE  ((column1=1 OR column1=3) AND
        (column2= 0 or column2= 4)
       ) AND (1)
GROUP BY 1,(2)
```

I don't know the meaning of "AND (1) GROUP BY 1,(2)" does anyone can explain it? , thank you

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: it is sqlite , I read it from a content provider

Comment: @GordonLinoff, is it actually you or your BOT commenting. When do you sleep? ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's format the query a little, that should help clear it up:

```
WHERE ((column1=1 OR column1=3) 
AND (column2= 0 or column2= 4) ) 
AND (1) 
GROUP BY 1,(2)
```

So the `AND (1)` part is the same as saying `AND (true)` or `AND (1=1)`. It always returns `true` so is effectively doing nothing.

The `GROUP BY` is just using the column position of your `SELECT`. So it's grouping byt the first column, then the second.

Comment: I doubt it. The query analyser would probably just ignore it anyway.